# Type 'MutableRefObject<HTMLParagraphElement | null>' is not assignable to type 'MutableRefObject<HTMLDivElement>

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typeerror

I am trying to build the app after testing it and this error occurs

[image]

I tried multiple methods shown in stack and other documentations but I am not very clear about the problem

Here is my code:

```js
type props = {
  html: React.MutableRefObject<HTMLDivElement>;
  data: any;
  rows: any;
};
```

Comment: Could you show us more code like how the `html` props been used?

Answer (score 0):

It was a minor mistake, I just assigned "html" with type any and the issue was solved.

i.e, html : any;

Comment: `any` is not type strong. try to keep properties with strong types